# How to find number of numbers in an array which are divisible by at least one another number in the same array

Tags: arrays

How to find number of numbers in an array which are divisible by at least one another number in the same array?

Ex : If the array is 1 2 3 4
The answer would be 3. Because, 2,3 and 4 are divisible by 1. 1 cannot be divided by any other no in the array

Can someone help me with an optimal solution (Better than brute force)

Comment: Is this a programming question? The implementation depends on what language you are using.

Comment: Yes. It is a programming question. Any language among C, C++, Java or Python is okay.

Answer (score 1):

```
array[t]                            -- array of t element
n = 0;                              -- divisible number in array
for (i=0; i<t; i++)
   for (j=0; j<t; j++)
       if ( i!=j &&                 -- not the same number
           array[i]%array[j]==0)    -- is divisible
               n++;                 -- number of divisible +1
```

Comment: Which language is this? Also, this could easily be optimised (which is likely to be necessary if the size of the list is large)

Comment: Hi, is simply the algorithm/structure :), for writing in c you should add the {}

Answer (score 0):

Try this method: (I used Java)

```
int divisible_count(int[] arr) {
   int count = 0;
     for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
         int count2=0;
         for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
             if(arr[i]%arr[j]==0){
                count2++;
                }
         }    
         if(count2 >=2){
            count++;
         }   
     }
return count;
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest a more optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using `py`thon:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4] ## Or whatever you want
divisibles = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    num = numbers[i]
    for j in range(len(numbers)):
        if j != i and num % numbers[j] == 0:
            divisibles.append(num)
            break
print(len(divisibles))
```

Comment: Can you suggest a more optimal solution?

Comment: @SanjayM It's likely that O(N^2) *is* the most optimal solution ... the main thing that can be reduced is (repeated) recomputation (which I *have* done), but that's mainly it. However, I think I *may* have found something of interest (I need to try a few things). If this is for a contest, please could you provide a link to the contest problem?